# Link in the message of jQnotice

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make a link that works in the following script. I use it as a pop-up, with the purchase of goods in a shop:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.buy').click(function() {
        jQnotice('Message..! - here i want to ad a url ex. "link go to shop" ');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JQnotice plugin this line

```
$('<div></div>').attr('id', 'notice').css('left', (50-left)+'%').css('top', (0+top)+'px').appendTo('body').text(message);
```

should be like this

```
$('<div></div>').attr('id', 'notice').css('left', (50-left)+'%').css('top', (0+top)+'px').appendTo('body').html(message);
```

Here is the link

http://jsbin.com/iwedah

Comment: I'd appreciate if you select my answer as correct answer by checking the tick on the left :) thanks

Comment: Hey, I still have a little trouble getting it to work ... When you click the button, the message window pops up properly, but the product will not put in the basket .. Have you some ideas how to fix it? - The code for the butotn looks like this: $if(User.VisibleBuy)$
     $if(it.IsBuyableQuick)$
      <span class="buy"><a href="$it.BuyableQuickUrl$" class="buy">$text.button_buy$</a></span>
                        
     $endif$

Answer (score 0):

The link should be:

```
  <a class='buy'>click me</a>
```

Since you are selectin links with class = buy.

Comment: Have you loaded all the libraries in the correct order?jquey first then jquerynotice?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="buy">Link</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.buy').click(function() {
        jQnotice('Message..!<a href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">Go to shop</a>');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/431/jQueryNotice-animated-notification-tooltip

Comment: Thank you, I still can not get it to work - the link does not seem to work - all code is there, does it makes more sense? http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/431/jQueryNotice-animated-notification-tooltip

Comment: Thank you, I still can not get it to work - the link does not seem to work - all code is there, it makes more sense? http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/431/jQueryNotice-animated-notification-tooltip